# How to denote a static Haskell URI in code with Network.URI?

Tags: haskell, uri

In the Haskell package [`Network.URI`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri) there is the `parseURI :: String -> Maybe URI` function.

I'd like to have a couple of static URIs in my code. Is it reasonable to write the following?

```
Just myURI = parseURI "http://google.com/"
```

The "problem" with this is that if the URI string is actually malformed, it is only caught at runtime with a pattern failed exception.

I'd like to avoid the tedium of constructing the `URI` datatype directly (which breaks apart the URI and makes it lose its conceptual meaning somewhat).

Is there a better way to have the static URI in code and be more "safe"?

Answer (score 6):

How about using Template Haskell to validate a static URL using `isURI` at compile time? It's safe to use `fromJust` at runtime now that the URL must be valid.

For example, define `staticURI` like this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module URI where

import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Network.URI (URI, isURI, parseURI)
import Language.Haskell.TH (Q, TExp)

staticURI :: String -> Q (TExp URI)
staticURI uri | isURI uri = [|| fromJust $ parseURI uri ||]
              | otherwise = fail $ "Invalid URI: " ++ uri
```

Then, you can define your URL in other modules like this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Network.URI (URI)
import URI (staticURI)

url :: URI
url = $$(staticURI "http://www.google.com/")

badUrl :: URI
badUrl = $$(staticURI "http://www.google.com/##")
```

When you pass a malformed URL to `staticURI`, a compiler will emit an error.

```
Invalid URI: http://www.google.com/##
In the Template Haskell splice
  $$(staticURI "http://www.google.com/##")
In the expression: $$(staticURI "http://www.google.com/##")
In an equation for ‘url’:
    url = $$(staticURI "http://www.google.com/##")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it reasonable to write the following?

No, don't pattern match with `Just` unless you are sure that your URI isn't malformed. A URI like this will give `Nothing` leading to runtime error:

```
λ> parseURI "http:/\\/google.com/"
Nothing
```

Instead, just represent the URI in `Maybe` type and do your computations on that using functions like `fmap` and others. One another way would be to check if it contains a valid URI using the function `isURI` or any of the other appropriate functions defined in [Network.URI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.0.3/docs/Network-URI.html) and then handle the appropriate cases:

```
λ> isURI "http:/\\/google.com/"
False
λ> isURI "http://google.com"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `URI` and `URIAuth` constructors directly. You get a bit more text, but you also get a static guarantee that you really do have a `URI`. But this is what you want to avoid :)

> I'd like to avoid the tedium of constructing the URI datatype directly
>   (which breaks apart the URI and makes it lose its conceptual meaning
>   somewhat).

If you're really set on using string literals, then you could turn on `OverloadedStrings` and define an `IsString` instance for `Maybe URI` like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String
import Network.URI

instance IsString (Maybe URI) where
    isString = parseURI

someUri :: Maybe URI
someUri = "http://google.ca"
```

You cannot safely dump the `Maybe`; you'll just have to work with it.